# npm packages not updating from package.json

Tags: angular, npm, asp.net-core, package.json

I have an Angular .NET core website that was created with the default 4.2.5 version. I'd like to update this to 5.2.7 (or later), and I've updated the package.json file to reflect this:

```
{
  "name": "JobWeb",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.7",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.10.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.5",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.10",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "0.20.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried to highlight all the packages in solution explorer and "update" that way. I have also tried to delete the node_packages folder and then do a restore. No matter what, I either end up with missing packages (exclamation on them), or it installs angular 4.2.5 again (and probably older versions of other stuff too). I used NCU to get my package.json file so it had the latest (or close to latest) versions of everything (which gave me angular 5.2.7, which would be fine), but I can't seem to get everything to actually install properly. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: In my experience, updating the version numbers in the *package.json*, saving that, and running `npm install` does the trick.

Comment: So what I ended up doing was deleting the node_modules directory, navigating to the directory where the package.json file is from a command prompt, and then run the npm install command. For some reason, it just wouldn't work doing it from VS, perhaps because things were in use.

Now the problem is that I can't open and debug my typescript files in Chrome anymore. I can't even see the JS files either.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity After using ncu whether the packages have updated in packages.json file. If yes means delete node_modules folder & reinstall again.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity VS installs its own copy of npm and uses that in preference of your installed npm by default.  You can change the path that VS uses for external tools by configuring Tools->Options, Projects and Solutions->Web Package Management->External Web Tools, and bumping $(PATH) ahead of $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External.  VS currently uses npm 3.3.4...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `node_modules` folder and run these commands `npm cache clean` and then `npm install` from the folder containing `package.json`. Also try downgrading the Typescript version to say 2.6.2.